# How to join two table hash in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm training ruby and I need to do an exercice but I don't know how to get data
I have this

```
DB = [
  {
    title: "My first article",
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id ratione harum illo, dicta minima rerum quod natus cupiditate voluptatibus rem! Amet reprehenderit voluptatum animi, eligendi quia quos reiciendis veritatis magni.",
    photo: "https://google.fr",
    rating: "2"
  },
  {
    title: "An second article",
    content: "Eventually the guys with real ideas not running a scam on the world will overcome. I used an exclamation just to be an asshole and also to make a point! LOL Young Thug is super inspiring to me. Amazing artist!!! I also wanted to point out that it’s the first album to go number 1 off of streaming!!! ",
    photo: "https://google.fr",
    rating: "2"
  },
  {
    title: "3 article",
    content: "also to Kim’s hair and makeup Lorraine jewelry and the whole style squad at Balmain and the Yeezy team. When companies doubt me they doubt us. Wes daytime",
    rating: "4"
  },
]


COMMENTS = [
  ["Hello1"],
  ["comment2"],
  ["comment3"],
]
```

and I would like this

```
 DATAS = [ {
        title: "My first article",
        content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id ratione harum illo, dicta minima rerum quod natus cupiditate voluptatibus rem! Amet reprehenderit voluptatum animi, eligendi quia quos reiciendis veritatis magni.",
        photo: "https://google.fr",
        rating: "2"
      }, ["Hello1"], 
....
    ]
```

If you can me it's will be very hepful because table for me it's quite hard, Thank you

Comment: This appears to be a pure-Ruby question, in which case you should not have the “Sinatra” tag.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write any code, so I won't give you a complete answer.

You could get the desired result with [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`Array#flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten).

`flatten` accepts an optional parameter for the number of nested arrays it should flatten.

So `DB.zip(COMMENTS).flatten` will be almost exactly what you want. You just need to provide the suitable parameter to `flatten`.

Comment: Hi Cary, long time no see! You can get an answer by concatenating the mentioned methods. ;)